# How do I add a custom Image to an HKWorkout in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchkit, healthkit

I am working on a workout App where users can save their workouts to HealthKit.
However, when I save the workout, it does not have an image in the Apple Fitness App overview. So my question is, how can I add this? I know that it works, because f.e. Matrix (provider of Gym Equipment) safes the Workouts with their Icon (see below).
[image][image: ][1]]

Comment: If you have been working on the app for a while create a new AppIcon file and fill in all the spaces.

Comment: I want to associate an Image with different Workouts. So my custom workout f.e. for running has a shoe, and a different custom workout for biking has a small bicycle.

I am looking for a way to safe an icon for specific workouts.

Comment: I have never tried but I don’t think that is possible. I am sure it is uses AppIcon. Maybe if you dig through the workout builder code but I don’t think so.

Comment: Your point with the AppIcon is good, but I just added the Icons and it is still not saved with an Icon. Also, I do not have a Matrix App installed. So when I connected my Watch to the Equipment, the icon had to be transferred to my watch.